# optionComponent & valueComponent is not working in react-select in latest version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select v2

here in its props `valueComponent` & `optionComponent`

which is get in deprecated in v2.

But if I switch to v1.3.. it works for me.

```
<Select
clearable={false}
searchable={false}
name='name-code'
value={this.props.selectedObj}
valueComponent={ValueComponent}
onChange={this.props.handlChange}
optionComponent={OptionComponent}
options={data} />
```

Thanks & appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

The props have been replaced by the [components api](https://react-select.com/components).
More information on that in the [upgrade documentation](https://react-select.com/upgrade-guide#new-components-api).